# Perl XML::Simple XMLout function

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I pass in the following XML to `XMLin`:

```
<root foo="bar" foo2="bar2">
<pizzas>
<pizza>Pepperoni</pizza>
</pizzas>
</root>
```

I then edit part of the root element via hash array.  I don't care about the pizza, but I do need that XML to come back out exactly as it was.  However, I get the following from `XMLout`:

```
<root foo="bar" foo2="bar2">
<pizzas pizza="Pepperoni"</pizzas>
</root>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that you did not use `ForceArray` with [XMLin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#ForceArray_=%3E_1_#_in_-_important).  Give that a try.  If that does not work, show us your Perl code.